Plane doesn't overlap marks in pgfplots
I'm trying to visualize how feature expansion makes linear inseparable data separable. For this I wanted to draw a plane between two mark clouds. The problem is that the plane is always drawn behind all marks, even though the green marks should be plotted behind the plane. I want them still to be seen, but through the transparent plane. How can I do this? Here is the code.
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            view={45}{45}, % Adjust the viewing angle
            zmin=0, zmax=5,
            xmin=1,xmax=9,
            ymin=1,ymax=9,
            xlabel=$X_1$,
            ylabel=$X_2$,
            zlabel=$X_1^k$
            ]
            \addplot3[only marks,ball color =red,
            mark = ball] coordinates {(8,3.2,4.05) (4.5,6.1,4) (9,5,3.9) (7,5.5,4.1) (6,2.1,3.94) (4.2,1.7,4) (3.5,3.8,4.18) (2.5,5.3,4.03)};
            \addplot3[only marks,ball color =green,
            mark = ball] coordinates {(5,3,1.04) (4.5,4.2,1) (5,5.3,0.94) (7,3,0.96) (7,4.5,1.1)};
            \addplot3[surf,domain=1:9, y domain=1:9,fill=yellow] {2.5}; 
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Explanation
Unfortunately, there is no algorithmic way to always ensure PGFPlots will render 3D graphs with the appropriate ordering of what objects appear above, and what objects appear below (called “z buffering”). The official documentation states,

Another issue which arises in three dimensional visualization is depth: it is necessary to decide which items are to be drawn in front of others... [PGFPlots] cannot combine different \addplot commands, those will be drawn in the order of appearance. You may encounter the limitations sometimes. Maybe it will be improved in future versions.
If you decide that you need high complexity, speed and 100% reliable z buffers (depth information), you should consider using other visualization tools and return to PGFPlots in several years.

However, in the case of your question, the situation is worse yet—although PGFPlots will happily render surfaces in the order of appearance in your code, the individual marks are rendered afterwards. This means that no matter how you re-order your code, the green marks will always appear above the yellow plane.
What can we do?
The limitation with PGFPlots is that the marks are always drawn last, so instead of using PGFPlots, I added the green balls on the graph by using normal TikZ. I then drew the yellow plane (and lowered the opacity to 0.4 so that you can see the green balls), and then the red balls. This is my result:

Code
Note that you must have \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11} in your preamble for this to succeed. This ensures that you can use TikZ directly with axis coordinates.
By the way, in your own preamble, you don't need \usepackage{tikz} and \usepackage{pgf}. By loading PGFPlots, these other packages are already loaded too.
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      view={45}{45}, % Adjust the viewing angle
      zmin=0, zmax=5,
      xmin=1, xmax=9,
      ymin=1, ymax=9,
      xlabel=$X_1$,
      ylabel=$X_2$,
      zlabel=$X_1^k$
    ]


    % Green points -------------------------------------
    \foreach \coord in {
      (5,   3,   1.04),
      (4.5, 4.2, 1   ),
      (5,   5.3, 0.94),
      (7,   3,   0.96),
      (7,   4.5, 1.1 )
    }{
      \edef\greenpoint{\noexpand\shadedraw[shading=ball, ball color=green] \coord circle (\pgfplotmarksize);}
      \greenpoint
    }


    % Yellow plane -------------------------------------
    \addplot3[surf, domain=1:9, y domain=1:9, fill=yellow, opacity=0.4] {2.5};


    % Red points ---------------------------------------
    \addplot3[only marks, mark = ball, ball color = red]
    coordinates {
      (8, 3.2, 4.05) (4.5, 6.1, 4) (9,   5,   3.9 ) (7,   5.5, 4.1)
      (6, 2.1, 3.94) (4.2, 1.7, 4) (3.5, 3.8, 4.18) (2.5, 5.3, 4.03)
    };


    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

